# Firestore: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to archive a project in Xcode. When pod 'Firebase/Firestore' is installed, I encounter the following issue:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor issue:

Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'RxLibrary'


Parse Issue:

Could not build module 'RxLibrary'
Could not build module 'GRPCClient'
Could not build module 'ProtoRPC'
```

The project is brand new.

The project can be archived successfully if I remove pod 'Firebase/Firestore'.

How can I fix this issue & still use Firestore?

Comment: Having the same issue. Are there any solutions or workarounds for this? Thanks.

Comment: This GitHub issue (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1266) suggests a workaround: The workaround is to comment #import "transformations/GRXMappingWriter.h" line from gRPC_RxLibrary-umbrella.h.

Comment: @p3scobar your words saved the day.... Thanks